# Decode url string in javascript

Tags: javascript, url, decode

I have this string:

```
http:\/\/www.google.com\/
```

And i want to change the url to :

```
http://www.google.com/
```

With :

```
url = url.replace(/\\//gi, "/");
```

But it give me empty string.

Any idea how i can fix it?

Comment: by fixing the rege to `/\\\//g`: `url.replace(/\\\//g,'/')`, escape both the backslash and the regex delimiting forward slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an extra backward slash. `\`

You could try this:

```
var url = 'http:\/\/www.google.com\/';
url.replace(/\\\//gi, "/");
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FUzJy/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
window.unescape('http:\/\/www.google.com\/')
```

Note however that this is not strictly URL encoding that has been applied to this string, because the `/` character is perfectly legal there.

Did it perhaps come from JSON, where the `/` character is supposed to be escaped?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [decodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

```
decodeURI('http:\/\/www.google.com\/')
//"http://www.google.com/"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **decodeURIComponent()** function which decodes a URI component.

```
var url="http:\/\/www.google.com\/";
url=decodeURIComponent(url);
```